# Moving an object towards a point android

Tags: java, android

I have this in the initialization of a bullet object:

```
    x = startX;
    y = startY;
    double distance = Math.sqrt(((endX - x) ^ 2) + ((endY - y) ^ 2));
    speedX = (6 * (endX - x)) / distance;
    speedY = (6 * (endY - y)) / distance;
```

It goes to where I touch on the screen, but the further away I touch, the faster it goes. This works fine on paper, I've tried it with different lengths and it should work, but bullets need to move 6 pixels on the line from the player to the point touched every step. And its update method moves of course. But why do bullets move at different speeds?

Comment: Although you'll need to normalize the vector before multiplying by 6 to get a fixed speed

Comment: You just want an independent distance speed? and also you still are missing the time variable.

Comment: How is speed applied to the object? I mean, is it on a per frame basis or just for every touch? Should it a constant value of six pixels (6 units) from the point of the bullet or what? You are multiplying by a fixed amount but without knowing how this is applied to the simulation it's impossible to answer you correctly.

Comment: Is ^ xor or power in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember my Java operators...

Replace

```
double distance = Math.sqrt(((endX - x) ^ 2) + ((endY - y) ^ 2));
```

with

```
double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(endX - x, 2) + Math.pow(endY - y, 2));
```

Comment: Ya, ^ is the logic gate XOR. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all measurements are in pixels and you want the speed to be 6 pixels per step, then you can calculate the velocity by using a little bit of trig:

```
double theta = Math.atan2(endY - startY, endX - startX);
velX = 6 * Math.cos(theta);
velY = 6 * Math.sin(theta);
```

Note that I am using the terms "speed" and "velocity" as a physicist would; speed is a scalar value and velocity is a vector with magnitude and direction.

Comment: X's should be cos, and Y's should be sin (so when atan returns 0 radiance you are moving rightward)

Comment: @Patashu Fixed! I really shouldn't try to answer questions when I'm so tired ;-(